# Checking whether a file is empty?

Tags: tex-core, filesystem-access

Well, the obvious way to do that is with `\ifeof`, but for some reason, I cannot do this right. I wrote

```
\newread\reader
\openin\reader=empty \relax
\ifeof\reader\message{empty}\else\message{not empty}\fi
\closein\reader
\openin\reader=notempty \relax
\ifeof\reader\message{empty}\else\message{not empty}\fi
\closein\reader
```

where `empty` is an empty file (sized 0), and `notempty` is non-empty file.
TeX seems to think that both files are not empty.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `\pdffilesize` for simple existence/empty tests:

```
\def\firstoftwo#1#2{#1}
\def\secondoftwo#1#2{#2}
\def\iffileexist#1{%
  \expandafter\ifx\expandafter&\pdffilesize{#1}&%
    \expandafter\secondoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\firstoftwo
  \fi
}
\def\iffileempty#1{%
  \ifnum0\pdffilesize{#1}>0
    \expandafter\secondoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\firstoftwo
  \fi
}
\def\test#1{%
  \iffileexist{#1}{File #1 exists}{File #1 doesn't exist}
  \iffileempty{#1}{File #1 is empty}{File #1 isn't empty}\par
}
\test{notexist}
\test{empty}
\test{nonempty}
\bye
```

For greater portability you should prefer the [`pdftexcmds` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdftexcmds) which makes `\pdf@filesize` available for both pdfTeX and LuaTeX.

Comment: @Phillip: I think this carves around TeX annoyance in an elegant way.

Answer (score 11):

Straight after opening a file `\ifeof` is false only when the file doesn't exist. You have not tried to read anything yet, so officially the end-of-file marker has not been found yet, even in the case where the file is empty. So you should try to read something from the file into a macro and then check both `\ifeof` and the macro you read into.

```
\newread\reader

\def\eolmarker{\par}

\def\testifempty#1{%
\openin\reader=#1\relax
\ifeof\reader
    \message{^^J#1: doesn't exist^^J}%
\else
    \read\reader to \readmacro
    \ifeof\reader
        \ifx\readmacro\eolmarker
            \message{^^J#1: is empty^^J}%
        \else
            \message{^^J#1: is not empty^^J}%
        \fi
    \else
        \message{^^J#1: is not empty^^J}%
    \fi
\fi
\closein\reader
}

\testifempty{empty}%   File "empty" is empty
\testifempty{notempty}% File "notempty" is not empty 
\testifempty{doesnotexist}% File "doesnotexist" doesn't exist

\bye
```

### Run using:

```
rm -f empty doesnotexist
touch empty
echo "not empty" > notempty
pdflatex <abovecode>.tex
```

### Result:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.11 (TeX Live 2010)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./f.tex 
empty: is empty

notempty: is not empty


doesnotexist: doesn't exists
 )
No pages of output.
Transcript written on f.log.
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. Take note that it also works if the non-empty file does not contain an eoln, i.e., if you produced with with `echo -a " " > notempty`.

Comment: I must confess I think this behavior of TeX is  a bit "clever" not say "ubersmart".

Comment: How can I make this work for files in which braces are not balanced?

Comment: @Hernan: Then you need to disable the normal meaning of braces before reading from the file. You then need to wrap the code into a group (`\begingroup`, `\endgroup`) so that the change is not global. The code would be like `\begingroup\let\do\@makeother\dospecials \read\reader to \readmacro \ifeof\reader\endgroup <then code> \else\endgroup <else code>\fi`. You need to place `\makeatletter` before and `\makeatother` behind the macro definition then to allow macros with an `@` symbol in them. See e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38910/2975 for a similar example.