# how to check in latex whether the table of content is empty or not before added to the document

Tags: table-of-contents

I have created a simple template for someone with the table of content added to the first page as follow

```
\begin{document}
    % title and date here 
    \maketitle
    \tableofcontents
    \indent \newline
    %  
\end{document}
```

But I figure out that someone don't add anything to the table of contents but there will be a word "Contents" shown in the document even the table is empty. Is that anyway I check in advance whether the table of contents is empty or not so to decide what to do next? Thanks.

Comment: My intuition tells me that you have to check if the the `.toc` file is empty or not. I'm not an expert of conditional statements in latex but maybe you can file some information [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12247/checking-whether-a-file-is-empty)

Comment: Thanks for your replies. To Pouya, since the latex will be run via php calling on the server side. I am wondering if that's possible for some case the .toc has not been cleaned so leads to a misleading judge? Well, buy the way, I don't know how to check the file remotely on the server too :(

Comment: *My* intuition tells me that you really ought to know/decide whether or not your document should have a TOC. Sorry to be grumpy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**update** The [etoc](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoc) package has a command since `v1.08e` to not print empty tables of contents. This is mainly for the case of local tables of contents but there is an additional switch also for global tables of contents (case of a batch processing of many documents some of which will have TOCs others not).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoc}
\etocchecksemptiness % do not display empty local table of contents
\etocnotocifnotoc % do not display empty global table of contents
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
% nothing will be printed if empty contents
\etocifwasempty {do something if was empty}
                {do something if was not empty}
document contents
\end{document}
```

---

I am updating this answer to provide a more flexible method, which assumes nothing about what the title of the table of contents is supposed to look like. As in my original answer, the point is that testing for existence or emptiness of the `.toc` file is not enough. With `babel` for example, there will always be some stuff in this file. Thus, we check if the file contains at least one `\contentsline` instance. In the new answer, the package [etoc](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoc) is used because it stores the contents of the `.toc` file in some internal register which we can check and then we set accordingly a toggle. Then `\tableofcontents` is redefined to first check this toggle. As long as `etoc` is left like here in compatibility mode, it will not modify the looks of the `TOC`. If `tocloft` is used it must be loaded before `etoc`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel} % for testing
\usepackage{hyperref}      % for testing

% Testing if the .toc file exists is not sufficient, (with Babel, there
% will be some info added to it automatically). We need to make
% sure it doesn't contain some \contentsline
\usepackage{etoc}

\newif\ifNonEmptyContents
\makeatletter
\expandafter\in@\expandafter\contentsline\expandafter{\the\Etoc@toctoks}%
\ifin@\expandafter\NonEmptyContentstrue\else
      \expandafter\NonEmptyContentsfalse
\fi
\makeatother

\AtBeginDocument{\let\originaltableofcontents\tableofcontents
  \renewcommand{\tableofcontents}%
     {\ifNonEmptyContents\expandafter\originaltableofcontents\fi}%
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents


% \section{A}
% a

% \section{B}

% b

% \subsection{C}

nothing
\end{document}
```

---

Initial answer:

Note though that there are some nice packages dealing with `TOC`'s which could well be upset by the following. Besides, I am assuming a standard `\tableofcontents` command as in the `article` class.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel} % for testing
\usepackage{hyperref}      % for testing

\newif\iftoctitledone

\makeatletter

\def\printcontentsnameifnotalreadydone{%
\iftoctitledone\else
\section *{\contentsname \@mkboth {\MakeUppercase \contentsname }
          {\MakeUppercase \contentsname }}\fi
\toctitledonetrue}


\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\mygoodoldcontentsline\contentsline
  \def\contentsline{\printcontentsnameifnotalreadydone\mygoodoldcontentsline}
  \renewcommand\tableofcontents{\@starttoc {toc}}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    \tableofcontents
    %  \section{test}
nothing
\end{document}
```

The same in another style, slightly more elegant.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel} % for testing
\usepackage{hyperref}      % for testing

\makeatletter

\def\printcontentsnameifnotalreadydone{%
\section *{\contentsname \@mkboth {\MakeUppercase \contentsname }
          {\MakeUppercase \contentsname }}%
\def\printcontentsnameifnotalreadydone{}}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\mygoodoldcontentsline\contentsline
  \def\contentsline{\printcontentsnameifnotalreadydone\mygoodoldcontentsline}
  \renewcommand\tableofcontents{\@starttoc {toc}}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    \tableofcontents
%    \section{A}
% a

% \section{B}

% b

% \subsection{C}

nothing
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the answer of jfbu:

How does this differ (except for the \@mkboth) from the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel} % for testing
\usepackage{hyperref}      % for testing

\makeatletter

\AtBeginDocument{%
     \let\oldcontentsline\contentsline
     \renewcommand{\contentsline}{
         \section*{\contentsname}
         \let\contentsline\oldcontentsline
         \oldcontentsline
     }
     \renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{\@starttoc{toc}}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
%    \section{A}
% a

% \section{B}

% b

% \subsection{C}

nothing
\end{document}
```

Comment: this is not an answer to the original question but a new question. Anyway, it differs a lot because the code you propose will insert a `Contents` heading  for each and every entry, be it `section`, `subsection` etc... ending up in the TOC. Try it out after un-commenting the sections in  the code you provide.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Comment: @AndrewSwann: IMHO it is not a new question, but a simplified version of jfbu's answer. And the "question" is more about, whether this simplification can be done or are there oversights.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek It is still not an answer, a comment on jfbu's answer, or an edit to the original question would appear to be more approrpiate.

Comment: @AndrewSwann: The code is different from jfbu's answer and provides a solution for the question. Therefore it qualifies for an answer to the question.