# Check whether tableofcontents is empty

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer

Inspired by [how to check in latex whether the table of content is empty or not before added to the document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94961/how-to-check-in-latex-whether-the-table-of-content-is-empty-or-not-before-added) I would like to have a head, that links to the table of contents if the toc is not empty, and does not link to it if it is empty. In the following I present a code for that. However, the parameter \TableofcontentsIsPrinted is not changed from FALSE to TRUE as it should. If it is renewcommand-ed in the \tableofcontents-definition it works at least in the sense that the head only links to the toc if \tableofcontents has been used in the document - but as I said, I would like to have the code check whether the toc is empty or not. Any help here?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\makeatletter

\newcommand{\TableofcontentsIsPrinted}{FALSE}
\newcommand{\printcontentsnameifnotalreadydone}{%
    \section*{\contentsname}%
    \renewcommand{\printcontentsnameifnotalreadydone}{}
    \renewcommand{\TableofcontentsIsPrinted}{TRUE} % Put in here, it does not work.
}
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \let\oldcontentsline\contentsline
    \renewcommand{\contentsline}{
        \printcontentsnameifnotalreadydone
        \oldcontentsline
    }
    \renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{%
        \@starttoc{toc}%
%       \renewcommand{\TableofcontentsIsPrinted}{TRUE} % Put in here, this works half-way.
    }
}

\newcommand{\remakehead}{
    \ifthenelse{ \equal{\TableofcontentsIsPrinted}{TRUE} }{
        \fancyhead[RO,LE]{ \hyperref[sec:tableofcontents]{ Page \thepage } }
    }{
        \fancyhead[RO,LE]{ Page \thepage }
    }
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{center} \Huge Heading \end{center}

\phantomsection
\tableofcontents
\label{sec:tableofcontents}
\remakehead

\newpage

\section{First Section}

\newpage

\section{Second Section}

\newpage

\end{document}
```

Comment: the main reason it does not work is that `\renewcommand{\TableofcontentsIsPrinted}{TRUE}` should be "global".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As using `TeX`'s conditionals defined with `\newif` is sometimes counter-intuitive and needs a somewhat extended apprenticeship, this update uses the [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) provided facilities `\newbool`, `\setbool` and `\ifbool` (or also `\newtoggle`, `\settoggle`, `\iftoggle`). There is no need then for package `ifthen` which the earlier version had used (with a boolean rather than a string comparison test) to minimally change the OP's `MWE`. Looking at the [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) documentation is recommended.

The redefinition of `\contentsline` has the effect that as soon as the new version is used it redefines itself to be its old self. Thus the added code (which displays the `TOC` title) is executed only once and additionally it sets a boolean (or toggle) to `true` (newly created conditionals are initially `false`). This is the flag which `\remakehead` tests to decide how to configure the header. This flag has to be set globally, as the `.toc` file will be executed within a group (this group is created via the action of the (unmodified) `\@starttoc` from the `LaTeX2e` kernel).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter

\newbool {TableofcontentsIsPrinted}
% or
%\newtoggle {TableofcontentsIsPrinted}

\AtBeginDocument{%
    \let\oldcontentsline\contentsline
    \renewcommand{\contentsline}{%
        \section*{\contentsname}%
        \global\setbool{TableofcontentsIsPrinted}{true}%
        % or \global\settoggle{TableofcontentsIsPrinted}{true}%
        \let\contentsline\oldcontentsline
        \contentsline }
    \renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{\@starttoc{toc}}
}

\newcommand{\remakehead}{%
    \ifbool {TableofcontentsIsPrinted}
    % or \iftoggle {TableofcontentsIsPrinted}
    {\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\hyperref[sec:tableofcontents]{Click me to
          get to contents}}}
    {\fancyhead[RO,LE]{Page \thepage}}%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{center} \Huge Heading \end{center}

\phantomsection
\tableofcontents
\label{sec:tableofcontents}
\remakehead

\newpage

\section{First Section}

\newpage

\section{Second Section}

\newpage

\end{document}
```

---

Try this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\makeatletter

\newif\ifTableofcontentsIsPrinted

\AtBeginDocument{%
    \let\oldcontentsline\contentsline
    \renewcommand{\contentsline}{%
        \section*{\contentsname}%
        \global\TableofcontentsIsPrintedtrue
        \let\contentsline\oldcontentsline
        \contentsline }
    \renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{\@starttoc{toc}}
}

\newcommand{\remakehead}{%
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{TableofcontentsIsPrinted}}
    {\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\hyperref[sec:tableofcontents]{Click me to
          get to contents}}}
    {\fancyhead[RO,LE]{Page \thepage}}%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{center} \Huge Heading \end{center}

\phantomsection
\tableofcontents
\label{sec:tableofcontents}
\remakehead

\newpage

\section{First Section}

\newpage

\section{Second Section}

\newpage

\end{document}
```

> [image: whether empty]
>
> [image: whether empty page 2]

Comment: Thanks, the code works. Could you explain in a bit detail how your code works? I understand the \let command, but not how the code in \renewcommand{\contentsline}{ ... } works. Also, could you explain how this with the boolean/if-thingy \ifTableofcontentsIsPrinteddo works? I am asking, because I want to learn and not just copy-paste.

Comment: `TeX` has a mechanism `\newif\ifMyIf` then `\MyIftrue` and `\MyIffalse` set it to true or false which then decides the branch taken `\ifMyIf <true branch>\else<false branch>\fi`. This original interface (see the `TeXbook` or `TeX by topic`) has many pitfalls though. I used it as you had `ifthenelse` loaded and were originally comparing strings which is less efficient, thus this was a minimal modification to preserve nevertheless your initial set-up.

Comment: If you look at a `.toc` file you will see a bunch of `\contentsline`. The redefinition here will impact only the very first one: because at the end it redefines itself to be its old unmodified self. The added patch sets the boolean to be true. We need a `\global` because the `TOC` is typeset within a group. Then `\remakehead` tests the value of the boolean and takes accordingly the appropriate decision regarding the header.