# Printing toc/lof/lot/others

Tags: table-of-contents, ifthenelse

How can I print toc only if isn't empty?

```
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}

%if there is a section, toc will be printed, else it wont be

\tableofcontents

%\section%in this case it wont be printed

A

\end{document}
```

Comment: related https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94961/how-to-check-in-latex-whether-the-table-of-content-is-empty-or-not-before-added and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169596/check-whether-tableofcontents-is-empty