# How to hide the \listoftables* if there are no tables in my document?

Tags: tables, table-of-contents

On this example, the list of tables is being shown, but there are no tables on it to show, then, it should not appear unless there are tables to list.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}

\begin{document}

\listoftables*

Contents.

\end{document}
```

[image]

How to hide the `\listoftables*` automatically if/when there are no tables in my document?

Answer (score 1):

you can redefine mem@listoftables, e.g. using pdffilesize to test for emptiness of \jobname.lot, see [answer to "Checking whether a file is empty?"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12247/checking-whether-a-file-is-empty). Commment out the table to see also the list of tables disappear.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}

\def\firstoftwo#1#2{#1}
\def\secondoftwo#1#2{#2}
\def\iffileexist#1{%
  \expandafter\ifx\expandafter&\pdffilesize{#1}&%
    \expandafter\secondoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\firstoftwo
  \fi
}
\def\iffileempty#1{%
  \ifnum0\pdffilesize{#1}>0
    \expandafter\secondoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\firstoftwo
  \fi
}

\makeatletter
  \@namedef{mem@listoftables}#1{%
    \ensureonecol
    \par
    \begingroup
    \iffileempty{\jobname.lot}{\relax}{%
      \@nameuse{@lotmaketitle}
      \if#1
        \ifmem@em@starred@listof\else
          \phantomsection
          \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}
        \fi
      \fi
      \parskip\cftparskip
      \@nameuse{cftlotbeforelisthook}%
    \@input{\jobname.lot}%
   }
    \if@filesw
      \AtEndDocument{%
        \expandafter\ifx\csname tf@lot\endcsname\relax
          \expandafter\newwrite\csname tf@lot\endcsname
          \immediate\openout \csname tf@lot\endcsname \jobname.lot\relax
        \fi
      }%
    \fi
      \@nobreakfalse
      \@nameuse{cftlotafterlisthook}%
    \endgroup
    \restorefromonecol}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\listoftables*

Contents.

\begin{table}
\caption{test tabel caption}
test table
\end{table}

\end{document}
```